# Error in display of fetch

Tags: php, mysqli

Upon running the snippet below, I get same number in symbol in all rows but other columns are different. I want all of them different

```
if($_POST['filter']>0 && $total<=totalRows($_POST['criteria'],$conn) && $total!=0)
                    {
                        $sql1="SELECT * FROM data AS d JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(symbol) FROM data)) AS symbol ) AS x WHERE d.symbol >= x.symbol AND d.division = '".$_POST['criteria']."' LIMIT ".$total;
                        echo '<div style="width:725px; border: thin; padding-left: 7px;">
                        Total Column of '.getDivision($_POST['criteria']).':'.totalRows($_POST['criteria'],$conn).'
                            <div style="float: right; width: 300px;">
                                Selection<br>
                                Division: '.getDivision($_POST['criteria']).'<br>
                            </div><br>
                        Entered value: '.$_POST['filter'].' '.$_POST['type'].'<br>
                        In Number: '.$total.'<br><br>
                        SQL Syntax:<br><div style="padding-left:5px;">'.$sql1.'</div></div><br><br>';
                        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
                            while($val1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
                            {
                                echo'<tr class="row100">
                                    <td class="column100 column1" data-column="column1">'.$val1['symbol'].'</td>
                                    <td class="column100 column2" data-column="column2">'.$val1['name'].'</td>
                                    <td class="column100 column3" data-column="column3">'.$val1['percent'].'</td>
                                    <td class="column100 column4" data-column="column4">'.getDivision($val1['division']).'</td>
                                </tr>';
                            }
                        }
```

Edit:
Use the following in $sql and desired output was obtained

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM data AS d JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT 
MAX(symbol) FROM data)) AS id ) AS x WHERE d.symbol >= x.id AND d.division = 
'".$_POST['criteria']."' LIMIT ".$total;
```

[image: More Description Here]

Comment: Have you tried checking the SQL query first? I don't think that you have a problem in outputting the data

Comment: Nico Haase, the code works perfectly in phpmyadmin mysql server and error as above is not seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to sql injections 2018
please use prepared statements and dont parse directly user values into your query

anyway your subquery is being cached... 
you should do your rand() in php since  SQL_NO_CACHE isnt allowed for that subquery